# C++ divide by zero

Tags: c++

I started to learn C++ programming and have a question about error handling.

I've made a code that calculates x from the function `ax+b=0` (so I have to divide `-b` by `a`). The values are entered by users via `cin >>`

If I divide by 0 i get `-int` as my output. Is it possible to catch the error (e.g. in with an `if` statement)?

I know that dividing by zero is impossible and I also know that it wouldn't be a good behavior form a program, if it doesn't check the user's input (e.g. `if ((a != 0)){calculate}`).  The thing is I would like to know how if/how it works to catch this error ;-) Does it depend on the hardware, operating system or compiler?

My teachers couldn't help me ;)

Btw. I use Eclipse Juno IDE for C/C++ on Mac OS X 10.8.2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a, b, x;   //float da Kommazahlen erwartet werden
    cout << "ax + b = 0" << '\n'<< endl;
    cout << "Bitte geben Sie einen Wert für a ein:" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Bitte geben Sie einen Wert für b ein:" << endl;
    cin >> b;

    x = -b/a;
    cout << "Ergebnis:" << x << endl;

    if (x == #INF )
    {
        cout << "Du bist a Volldepp - durch Null kann man nicht teilen!" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++ dividing by 0 doesn't necessairly have to throw you an exception, so you have to manually check for that your self via if-statement

Comment: Your statement state "Du bist a Volldepp - durch Null kann man nicht teilen!"? is not correct. Actually x / 0 is a shortcut for the solution of y * 0 = x. Depending on the value and the domain of x there may be 0, infinitely many, 1, 2, 3 or any other number of solutions.

Comment: @udoKlein i agree with you. e.g. if b=0 and a=0 b/a => 0:0=infinitely so i' ll change it to "i cannot give you correct an awnswer - it makes me sad" ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes:

In C++03

```
 if ((x == +std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()) || 
     (x == -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
    )
```

In C++11

```
 if (std::isinf(x))
```

Comment: thx a lot. I changed the code a little bit. Now it would only output results =! 0

`x = -b/a;

     if ((x == +std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()) ||
             (x == -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity())
            ){
         cout << "This makes me sad." <<endl;

        }
     else{
      cout << "Ergebnis:" << x << endl;

     }`

Comment: Since C++11, there's std::isinf(...). Is there any reason to still prefer your solution?

Comment: @Ela782: Updated to match the times.

Comment: It is worth noting that 0/0 would produce NaN and not Inf, so that case would be unchecked unless you also add `std::isnan(x)`.

Answer (score 4):

Just check whether `a == 0` before attempting the division:

```
if (a == 0) {
    std::cerr << "I'm not even going to try\n";
    return 1;
} else {
    std::cout << "-b/a = " << (-b/a) << std::endl;
}
```

That may still produce `inf` for some very small numbers, though.

(Note that in general, checking whether a `float` is equal to some value is [not reliable because of round-off errors](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/), but for zero it's ok.)

Comment: Um, "not reliable" is rather harsh. Conversions from text to floating-point values do not do exactly what a naive user expects. But a "nearly equal" comparison, as suggested in that link, is an advanced technique. For beginners it will create more confusion.

Comment: @PeteBecker: the OP already knows about platform-dependent behavior and the like, so I guessed that this "advanced" trick wouldn't be too scary.

Comment: It's never too early for a programmer to learn how to deal correctly with floats.

Comment: It's not that it's scary, it's that it produces anomalous results, regardless of the platform. Validating input should not be done with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @PeteBecker: turns out I had removed the "but for zero it's ok" from an earlier version. I don't actually recommend this for this simple program.

Comment: thanks for your replies. as i mentioned above i do know the way of checking the input. What i wanted to know was how to deal with the -inf error (just if it happens - never mind if it means that the programm is bad) because my teacher did not have a solution for that.
But your awnswer are very interesting as I also din't heard about ::cerr (::clog) before. I also try to understand your linked article ;-) THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 1):

You should check for correctness of input before you calculate, not afterwards:

```
if ( a == 0 ) {
 if ( b == 0 )
   cout << "equation valid for all x" << endl;
 else
   cout << "no x satisfies this equation" << endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do know that it wouln't be a good way if iam not going to check the input. I've also figured out if (a!=0){do the math) else{error} but i basically want to knwo how to deal with such kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, best way to handle this situation is a==0 condition. Divide by zero is not an exception, it is handled at hardware level. The hardware sends interrupt to OS and OS to your application thus crashing it.
It can be captured with signal:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void handler(int nVal) 
{
    cout << "Divid By Zero Error" << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    signal(SIGFPE, handler);
    int nVal = 1/0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, does it only work for int? if i change int to float (as mine output will be) i am getting an error while compiling the code.

Answer (score 1):

I echo the other posters in saying that you should check your arguments, but there is an alternative: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling

According to that link, in C++11, you can set a `#define` to make it so that when you divide by zero it will throw exceptions of type `FE_DIVBYZERO`.  But the documentation on that page is NOT clear, so investigate to see if your own compiler supports this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not Catch the Exception in `C` but you can avoid it by checking the Value..

Try like this, It will help you

```
if (a == 0) {
  x = 0;
} else {
  x = b/a;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because your math is wrong.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard: What Math is Wrong..?

Comment: Yours. `0x + b = 0` does not mean `x == 0`. See other answers for clarification.